# Подключение java скрипта в частичное представление подгружаемое Ajaxом

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap

Всем привет.
использую "select2" данный компонент предоставляет из себя Выпадающий список с возможностью редактирования и фильтрации. Подключаю необходимые скрипты/стили и вывожу на представление. При переходе на страницу где используется данный компонент все работает, а проблема заключается в следующем: в представлении есть ajax форма которая добавляет в бд запись и делает редирект на метод возвращающий частиыное представление. после загрузки частичного представления компонент перестает работать(т.е. становится обычным полем для ввода)

Upd:
на текущий момент проблему решил переносом скрипта в текст представления
т.е. счас это выглядит как то так:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOrderItem", "Order", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabItems", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    //здесь поля для ввода
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".select2").each(function () {
        var url = this.dataset.url;
        $(this).select2({
            allowClear: true,
            minimumInputLength: 1,  // minimumInputLength for sending ajax request to server
            width: 'resolve',   // to adjust proper width of select2 wrapped elements 
            ajax: {
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        searchStr: term,
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return { results: data.list }; // data.CountryList returning json data from Controlle
                }
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

вот только мучают сомнения в правильности данного решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решение было найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941052/javascript-not-working-in-partial-view)

```
public static IHtmlString Resource(this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> Template, string Type)
{
    if (HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Type] != null) ((List<Func<object, HelperResult>>)HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Type]).Add(Template);
    else HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Type] = new List<Func<object, HelperResult>>() { Template };

    return new HtmlString(String.Empty);
}

public static IHtmlString RenderResources(this HtmlHelper HtmlHelper, string Type)
{
    if (HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Type] != null)
    {
        List<Func<object, HelperResult>> Resources = (List<Func<object, HelperResult>>)HtmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[Type];

        foreach (var Resource in Resources)
        {
            if (Resource != null) HtmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(Resource(null));
        }
    }

    return new HtmlString(String.Empty);
}

//код из частичного представления
@Html.Resource(@<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/OrderItems.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>, "js")
@Html.RenderResources("js")
```