# Javascript и частичное представление

Tags: jquery, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431729/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-java-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-ajax%D0%BE%D0%BC/432737#432737) я решил проблему с подключением "js" кода в частичное представление но на этом не остановился и нашел для себя следующую проблему. Если подключить "js" на главной странице("_Layout.cshtml") то код доступен при первоначальной загрузке страницы, но после обновления(загрузка средствами ajax) перестает работать, если же подключить в частичном представлении то ситуация обратная, а подключать скрипт два раза тоже как то неправильно. Так вот сам вопрос: Как Вы поступаете в таком случае?

**Upd:**

javascript

```
$('.select2').each(function () {
    var url = this.dataset.url;
    $(this).select2({
        delay: 100,
        allowClear: true,
        minimumInputLength: 1,  // minimumInputLength for sending ajax request to server
        width: 'resolve',   // to adjust proper width of select2 wrapped elements 
        ajax: {
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    searchStr: term,
                };
            },
            results: function (data) {
                return { results: data.list }; // data.CountryList returning json data from Controller
            }
        }
    })
})
```

частичное представление

```
<div id="tabItems">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOrderItem", "Order", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tabItems", HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { id = "AddItem" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderId, new { id="OrderId" })

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductId, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "ProductId", @class = "form-control select2",
                        data_url = @Url.Action("GetProductList", "Order"), data_placeholder = "Select a product" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductNodeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "ProductNodeId", @class = "form-control select2",
                        data_url = @Url.Action("GetProductNodeList", "Order") } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductNodeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToolId, new { htmlAttributes = new { id="ToolId", @class = "form-control select2",
                        data_url = @Url.Action("GetToolList", "Order") } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ToolId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmountRequired, new { htmlAttributes = new { id="AmountRequired", @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AmountRequired, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <a href="#" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

код контроллера

```
public ActionResult AddOrderItem(AddOItemModel model)
{
    //здесь какой то код
    return RedirectToAction("GetOrderItems", new {orderId = model.OrderId})
}

public ActionResult GetOrderItems(int orderId)
{
    var model=//получение модели для представления
    return PartialView("Items",model)
}
```

**UPD2:**
скрипт принял такой вид

```
$('body').on('click', '.select2', function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        var url = this.dataset.url;
        $(this).select2({
            delay: 100,
            allowclear: true,
            minimuminputlength: 1,  // minimuminputlength for sending ajax request to server
            width: 'resolve',   // to adjust proper width of select2 wrapped elements 
            ajax: {
                url: url,
                type: "get",
                datatype: 'json',
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        searchstr: term,
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return { results: data.list }; // data.countrylist returning json data from controller
                }
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю: у вас перерисовывается часть *html* и после этого перестает раблтать *JS* для этой части *html*?

Comment: да, Вы меня поняли правильно. есть блок <div id="Result"></div> который обновляется следующим образом @Ajax.ActionLink("Method","Controller", new AjaxOption{UpdateTargetId="Result"});

Comment: Думаю в данном вопросе абсолютно не важно как обновляется ваш *HTML*. Очевидно проблемма в *JS*. Приведите пожалуйста пример вашего *JavaScript* и кусок *HTML* который вставляется в разметку.

Comment: обновил вопрос, javascript привел как он есть. т.е. у меня так написан он в файле tabItems.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Кто виноват:

Код `$('.select2')` возвращает список *jQuery* объектов у которых внутри есть ссылка на объект(ноду) из *DOM* (*Document Object Model*). К этим объектам применяется  функция которую вы описали в `each`.

После обновления части *HTML* *ajax*-ом все *DOM* объекты в этой части *HTML* пересоздаются и соответственно Ваша функция из `each` к ним не применяется. А те объекты, к которым Вы применили Вашу функцию, бесследно исчезли.

> На самом деле несовсем бесследно, подобные вещи могут приводить к утечкам памяти в *JavaScript* и другим интересным последствиям, но для небольшого приложения на это можно закрыть глаза.

### Что делать:

Самый очевидный вариант решения проблемы: не писать код зависящий от объектов которые могут пересоздаваться.

Например если Вам нужно подписаться на событие то вместо кода:

`$('.select2').on('click', function (){...})`

лучше использовать:

`$('body').on('click', '.select2', function (){...})`

> Такой код облегчит жизнь не только Вам но и браузеру, так-как ему нужно будет добавить только один обработчик события а не несколько (для каждого элемента `'.select2'`) как в случае `$('.select2')`.

#### Как подключать виджеты:

Если виджет никак себя не выдает до того как пользователь начнет выполнять действия с элементом, то Вы можете подключить виджет на определенное событие, например:

```
$('body').on('click', '.select2', function (e){
     $(e.target).select2();
})
```

Но такой вариант подойдет если виджет нормально отрабатывает ситуации двойного подключения к одному элементу. Но насколько я понимаю Ваш виджет к таким не относятся. *select2* [кинет ошибку](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/src/js/jquery.select2.js#L29).
Обойти это можно так:

```
$('body').on('click', '.select2', function (e){
     var $target = $(e.target);
     if (!$target.data('select2')) {
         $target.select2();
     }
})
```

Если Вам нужно подключить виджет сразу после обновления части *HTML*, то я Вам рекомендую вынести код в отдельную функцию, которая будет вызывать инициализацию виджетов, и вызывать эту функцию каждый раз после обновления *HTML* *ajax*-ом.

Где-то в *_Layout.cshtml*:

```
MY_APP.init_select2 = function () {
    $('.select2').each(function () {/* Ваш код */})
}
```

где `MY_APP` - глобальная переменная.

В частичном представлении:

```
<script>MY_APP.init_select2();</script>
```

Если конечно нет другого способа узнать об обновлении куска *HTML* прямо в *JS*.

Ответ получился большой, надеюсь тут мало воды и очевидных вещей.

Comment: спасибо Вам большое. очень помогли. А можете посоветовать какую нибудь книгу для уровня 0, что бы ознакомится с рекомендациями как надо писать код.

Comment: Мне сложно ответить на этот вопрос, так как я сам изучал *JS* методом проб и ошибок. Но пару ссылок я все равно оставлю: [Курс](http://goo.gl/2srT9r) по *JS*, и только по *JS*. Да если вас привлекает формат онлайн курсов, посетите эти платформы: [tuts+](http://tutsplus.com/), [treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/), [codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/). Ну и классика для чтения [как работают браузеры](http://goo.gl/E9p6Ax) большая, нудная но полезная статья, [Паттерны в JS  от Addy Osmani](http://goo.gl/iIERIC), [Выразительный JavaScript](http://goo.gl/bU5yxC)